# How would one go about creating a watchlist?

Tags: php

I have two tables, one with products and a foreign key for the customer. The other is a watchlist with the product id and the fk for the customer.

How would I go about looping the product information from the products table where the fk matches the session id in the watchlist?

My mind is blank and google isn't helping!

Many thanks.

Comment: What are you looping through?  What do you want to do, exactly?

Comment: please attach table structures. `SHOW CREATE TABLE` syntax should be enough.

Comment: The question is still not clear to be. But I think, a `JOIN` in the SELECT query is what you are looking for. That is, you want to select the product details of those users that watches some products. So to get the details, use a SELECT query by joining the tables using the KEY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example tables:

```
Products
--------
id (PK)
name
price
description


Customers
---------
id (PK)
firstName
lastName
email
phone


WatchList
---------
customerID (FK)
itemID (FK)
```

Get a customers watch list:

```
SELECT Products.name, Customers.email
FROM WatchList
JOIN Customers ON WatchList.customerID = Customers.ID
JOIN Products ON WatchList.itemID = Products.ID
WHERE Customers.ID = <insert customer id here>
```

Comment: That looks right! and then just mysql rows them to varibles?

Comment: @KyleGravvit: Yup, just look up php-mysql tutorial for fetching field value from a query.